Rendering task update messages as they are completed in Shiny App
Within an observer button event, I'm trying to render an update message to the Shiny UI upon completion. In the code below, each task is timestamped correctly however they aren't rendered to the UI until the end.
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Task Renderer"),
  mainPanel(
    h3("Completed Tasks:"),
    verbatimTextOutput("task_output"),
    actionButton("process_button", "Process")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  milestones <- c("Task 1: Data collection", 
                 "Task 2: Data cleaning", 
                 "Task 3: Data analysis", 
                 "Task 4: Model building", 
                 "Task 5: Model evaluation", 
                 "Task 6: Report generation")
  
  current_task <- reactiveVal(0)
  completed_tasks <- reactiveVal(character())
  
  nextTask <- function() {
    task_index <- current_task() + 1
    if (task_index <= length(milestones)) {
      current_task(task_index)
      current_time <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      completed_tasks(c(completed_tasks(), paste(milestones[task_index], "-", current_time)))
      invalidateLater(1000)  # Trigger UI update after 1 second
    }
  }
  
  output$task_output <- renderText({
    task_index <- current_task()
    if (task_index > 0) {
      paste(completed_tasks(), collapse = "\n")
    } else {
      "No tasks completed yet."
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$process_button, {
    # Reset current task and completed tasks
    current_task(0)
    completed_tasks(character())

    #simulate next bit of code
    Sys.sleep(5)
    nextTask() #render task complete message as each is finished

    #simulate next bit of code
    Sys.sleep(5)
    nextTask() #render task complete message as each is finished

    #simulate next bit of code
    Sys.sleep(5)
    nextTask() #render task complete message as each is finished
    })
  }


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

I've tried moving the function in and out of the button event code block and several tries with different reactive configurations

Welcome to SO.  This is expected behaviour: shiny is, by default, single threaded.  However, recent deveopments have add ExtendedTask to Shiny.  That sounds exactly like what you want.  See here for details.

Good tip, I'll check that out!

If you don't want to go the async route, you can use withProgress/setProgress to display task information in a more limited fashion. But in general outputs are rendered only once all reactives and observers have completed, so it's quite difficult to show incremental progress in arbitrary outputs.
